# Leetcode Three Sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, subset-sum-problem

From [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/):

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
>
> Note:
>
> The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

This solution works and is pretty fast but not very memory efficient. I have some comments which I added when writing it to keep track of what I was doing. Specific questions are at bottom.

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        # Early exit conditions
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return []            

        results = {}
        vals = {}
        # Make easy to check if all target values exist
        for i, v in enumerate(nums):
            if v in vals:
                vals[v] += 1
            else:
                vals[v] = 1

        # Go through all matching numbers 
        # This works because each result is unique
        for i, num in enumerate(vals.keys()):

            # Modified two sum problem to get -i-j
            for j in list(vals.keys())[i:]:

                # If checking itself but only is in input once, can't work
                if num == j and vals[num] < 2:
                    continue

                target_val = -(num+j) 
                if target_val in vals:
                    valid = False
                    if vals[target_val] > 2:
                        valid = True
                    else:
                        # Check that this isn't either i/j (thus duplicate)
                        if num != target_val and j != target_val:
                            valid = True

                    if valid and tuple(sorted((num, j, target_val))) not in results: 
                        results[tuple(sorted((num, j, target_val)))] = True

        return [list(r) for r in results.keys()]
```

1. I dislike the way I'm sorting then converting to a tuple. Is there a better way to do this?
2. I feel like I can clean up some of the `if` logic but I'm not totally sure how is best.
3. I dislike the `list(vals.keys())` approach - is there a better way to do what I'm doing here? I am not a huge fan of it
4. This one might be out of scope for this Code Review question but this doesn't seem to generalize very well if there were say 4 elements or 8 elements in the target (vs 3). I'd have to continue to add nested lists in order for that to work and the strategy for `if` checking here would get *very* messy.

Comment: Is it passing all the test cases?

Comment: Yes this passes all test cases.

Answer (score 5):

For reference, what I think is the most straightforward solution, that is *not* fast enough since it does all combinations of three.

```
from itertools import combinations

class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        return set(tuple(c) for c in combinations(sorted(nums), 3) if sum(c) == 0)
```

And a longer, but valid solution.

- Take positive and negative numbers separately.
- Add all combinations of two positive numbers where their negative sum is among the negative numbers. Repeat for negative numbers.
- For each number in both negative and positive, add `-n, 0, n`
- If there are three or more zeroes, add `0,0,0`

```py
from itertools import combinations

class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        positive = sorted([n for n in nums if n > 0])
        posSet = set(positive)
        negative = sorted([n for n in nums if n < 0])
        negSet = set(negative)
        zeroes = nums.count(0)
        valid = set((a,b,0-a-b) for (a,b) in combinations(positive, 2) if 0-a-b in negSet)
        valid = valid.union(set((a,b,0-a-b) for (a,b) in combinations(negative, 2) if 0-a-b in posSet))
        if(zeroes > 0):
            valid = valid.union(set((-a,0,a) for a in positive if 0-a in negSet))
        if(zeroes > 2):
            valid.add((0,0,0))
        return valid
```

Surprisingly good results:

*Runtime: 360 ms, faster than 98.52% of Python3 online submissions for 3Sum.
Memory Usage: 16.4 MB, less than 97.14% of Python3 online submissions for 3Sum.*

Answer (score 4):

1. Please don't have white space at the end of lines. There is never a need for anything other than a new line at the end of a line.
2. You don't need to use `enumerate(nums)` to build `vals` - `i` is never used.
3. You can use `collections.defaultdict(int)` to remove the need for the `if` in the `for` when you make `vals`.
4. You can use `collections.Counter` to create `vals`.
5. You can use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to reduce your nested for loops into one. This has the same \$O\$, but may help in the future if you want to do four sum.
6. It is confusing to use `i` and `j` to not be related to the same thing. `i` is "index", where `j` is "num2".
7. Since `valid` is just a Boolean, you can compress the `if`-`else` to not need the `if`.
8. I believe your `vaild` check is erroneous. If `j` and `target_val` are the same but `vals[j] == 1` then your code will happily still plop it out. I also think your output is erroneous on `num == j` and `vals[num] == 2`.

   You can make a `collections.Counter` of the values and then check if this counter is a subset of the global one.
9. I suggest making two functions:

   1. A generator function, one that produces values that add to the desired sum.
   2. A function to filter duplicate values and normalize output.

```
class Solution:
    def _three_sum(self, nums: List[int]) -> Iterator[Tuple[int, int, int]]:
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return

        vals = set(nums)
        for i, j in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(vals, 2):
            k = -(i+j)
            if k not in vals:
                continue
            yield i, j, k

    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        output = set()
        amounts = collections.Counter(nums)
        for result in self._three_sum(nums):
            if all(
                amount <= amounts[num]
                for num, amount in collections.Counter(result).items()
            ):
                output.add(tuple(sorted(result)))
        return [list(vals) for vals in output]
```

---

To answer your questions:

1. No.
2. If you change `_three_sum` to `_n_sum` then the `threeSum` function will work fine.
3. I'm not sure what you mean by it but, `list(vals)` is a Pythonic way to write it. Albeit possibly more confusing. It is preferred to just use `itertools`.
4. This is off-topic here, and no this would probably not be extendable to more than sum of three.

   I know of [this answer on CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/108835) that sets the foundation for an n-sum solution. Whilst the question clearly has a different goal, you should be able to dissect the answer and mold it to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked @JollyJoker's answer but it was not written in Pythonic enough format for my taste. I added some changes that take his core logic and improve upon it:

```py
from itertools import combinations

class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        positive = sorted(n for n in nums if n > 0)
        posSet = set(positive)
        negative = sorted(n for n in nums if n < 0)
        negSet = set(negative)
        zeroes = nums.count(0)
        valid = {(a, b, -a-b) for (a,b) in combinations(positive, 2) if -a-b in negSet}
        valid.update((a, b, -a-b) for (a,b) in combinations(negative, 2) if -a-b in posSet)
        if zeroes > 0:
            valid.update((-a, 0, a) for a in positive if -a in negSet)
            if zeroes > 2:
                valid.add((0, 0, 0))
        return valid
```

Results:

*Runtime: 340 ms, faster than 98.68% of Python3 online submissions for 3Sum.*

*Memory Usage: 16.6 MB, less than 77.86% of Python3 online submissions for 3Sum.*